# How to find a maximimum with given constraints in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, solver

For a given set of players, player positions, player cost, a budget and a set of constraints, how can I find the "optimal" solution? For example:

```
ID - Pos - cost - pts
1     1     13    10
2     1     5     13
3     2     10    15
4     2     10     8
5     3     12    12
6     3     7     14
```

and a budget of 30 (total cost cannot exceed 30), limitation of 1 player per position.

The real problem I'm trying to solve is: I have estimated points per player in fantasy football. Now given the constraints in fantasy football, i.e.

1. a budget of 100
2. 1 goalkeeper
3. a max of 5 defenders, min of 3 defenders
4. a max of 5 midfielders, min of 3 midfielders
5. a max of 3 strikers, min of 1 striker

Given these constraints, how do I find the maximum pts?

What libraries and tools are available for something like this? I could imagine myself doing this in Excel solver, but given my dataset with over 1000 players it wouldn't work.

I started writing some custom code, but quickly realized there must be some readymade solutions for this.

Comment: This is more so a math problem (optimization) than a programming problem. You could probably find optimization libraries online, and depending on your problem type, you can select the appropriate algorithm. You should first specifiy your _objective function_ (or criterium) to be optimized. This is not clear from your Q. (Is it the number of points?)

Comment: Maybe scipy could help here, but without more details (what are the constraints and what is to be optimized) it is hard to say whether it is appropriate here or whether custom code should be enough. Moreover, asking for libraries or other off site resources is off topic on SO because it attracts opinion or link only answers

Comment: I updated the answer to be more specific. I didin't intend to directly ask for links. I'm just quite lost on where to even start looking. I feel like a custom solution might be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-optimize is a good starting point
https://scikit-optimize.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the knapsack problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with the additional constraint, that same positions can't go together, which has been discussed here before:

[Knapsack with items to consider constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973662/knapsack-with-items-to-consider-constraint)

As stated there the problem is NP-hard.

You might have a look at the itertools module to reduce the runtime of your computation.